# JSON vs Form POST

Tags: json, rest, post, http-post

We're having a bit of a discussion on the subject of posting data to a REST endpoint. Since the objects are quite complex, the easiest solution is to simply serialize them as JSON and send this in the request body.

Now the question is this: Is this kosher? Or should the JSON be set as a form parameter like data=[JSON]? Or is sending of JSON in the request body just frowned upon for forcing the clients using the application, to send their data via JavaScript instead of letting the browser package it up as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

I know all three options *work*. But which are *OK*? Or at least *recommended*?

Comment: I am interested in the outcome of this discussion. Is there any update? My current understanding is that, JSON content should be passed as part of POST data, and any optional parameter can still be sent as part of URL parameters. This is how twitter REST API implement it.. just as a reference.

Answer (score 29):

I'd say that both methods will work well
 it's important that you stay consistent across your APIs. The option I would personally choose is simply sending the content as `application/json`.

`POST` doesn't force you to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - it's simply something that's used a lot because it's what webbrowsers use.

Comment: Is there a reason why most web browsers use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as opposed to `application/json`? It seems to me that `application/json` is more flexible and expressive.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong about sending it directly as serialized JSON, for example **google does this by default** in it's `volley` library (which obviously is their *recommended* REST library for android).

If fact, there are plenty of questions on SO about how **not to** use JSON, but rather perform "normal" POST requests with volley. Which is a bit counter intuitive for beginners, having to overwrite it's base class' `getParams()` method.

But google having it's own REST library doing this by default, would be my indicator that it is *OK*.

Answer (score 7):

You can use JSON as part of the request data as the OP had stated all three options work.

The OP needs to support JSON input as it had to support contain complex structural content.  However, think of it this way... are you making a request to do something or are you just sending what is basically *document* data and you just happen to use the `POST` operation as the equivalent of create new entry.

That being the case, what you have is basically a **resource endpoint** with CRUDL semantics.  Following up on that you're actually not limited to `application/json` but any type that the resource endpoint is supposed to handle.

#### For non-resource endpoints

I find that (specifically for JAX-RS) the `application/x-www-urlencoded` one is better.

1. Consistency with OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect, they use `application/x-www-urlencoded`.
2. Easier to annotate the individual fields using Swagger Annotations
3. Swagger provides more defaults.
4. Postman generates a nice form for you to fill out and makes things easier to test.

Examples of non-resource endpoints:

- Authentication
- Authorization
- Simple Search (though I would use `GET` on this one)
- Non-simple search where there are many criteria
- Sending a message/document (though I would also consider `multipart/form-data` so I can pass meta data along with the content, but JAX-RS does not have a standard for this one Jersey and RestEasy have their own implementations)