# Should Rest API accept POST array or JSON string?

Tags: php, json, api, rest

I've been reading a few REST tutorials and some of them says that in order to send data to a rest API you should send post data as an array, which is something like this:

```
$data = array('foo' => 'bar');
$rest->post($data);
```

Then there are others that say you should send JSON data like this:

```
$data = array('foo' => 'bar');
$data = json_encode($data);
$rest->post($data);
```

Not sure if there's a standard way of doing this or either if is fine but what is generally recommended when designing API's?

EDIT: There seems to be confusion. To clarify I agree JSON should be used for client consumption but this question is about SERVER consumption. Meaning should the SERVER accept JSON or POST data from its clients?

Comment: It depends on what this will be used for, if it will be used from something like JS JSON input might be better

Comment: This discussion might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604717/json-vs-form-post

Answer (score 7):

If you're the one creating the RESTful API, meaning your application is the *server* and is accepting requests, then your question seems confusing.  Your application will not be sending any `POST` data; *clients* will be sending `POST` data to you.

With that being said, having an API which will accept JSON-encoded requests is possible, though would really only be useful for very niche scenarios.  The vast majority of clients will be POSTing data to your API in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.  PHP handles this behind the scenes for you, and exposes the data as the `$_POST` superglobal.

If you're talking about *responding* to POST requests, and what format you should use, then that will depend on what format the *client* wants you to send it in.  The client will either specify this in the `Accept` header, or some APIs allow it to be specified in the URL (e.g. `foo.com/some/thing/123.json` or `foo.com/some/thing/123/json`).  The client isn't required to tell your application what format it wants, so it's up to you to pick a sensible default.  Most APIs will use JSON these days.

I've never heard of an API that understood serialized PHP array format, though, so I don't know what resources you've been reading, but I'm pretty sure you misunderstood what they were suggesting.

Comment: I am the one creating API and this question makes perfect sense because if the client sends me (the server) a JSON string I cannot read it with `$_POST`, I need to use other means (e.g., `parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $data);`). So this question is important because both ways are possible (JSON or POST array). The consensus is JSON is universal but as you said, some will use POST array so that is the reason of my question. Which is which?

Comment: I am pretty sure you misunderstood me, just in case it isn't clear, this has nothing to do with client consumption of data, I agree JSON is king for client consumption. This is about the server allowing clients to SEND (not receive) JSON or POST data.

Comment: @IMB: If you're talking about clients sending you JSON data, then why did you post an examples in PHP?

Comment: @IMB: Regardless, I mentioned in my answer above that you can accept JSON on the server-side.  As you pointed out, reading from `php://input` will be how you handle this.  If the incoming `Content-Type` values is `application/json` then you will read the data and use `json_decode()` to decode it.  It's relatively common for APIs to support this, but in practice, I don't know how often it's actually used.  Like I mentioned, most requests will be URL encoded, rather than JSON encoded.

Comment: If you look my example they send both JSON and PHP.

Comment: @IMB:  I don't think you understand.  Your examples are _written in_ PHP.  Only _clients_ will be POSTing anything, and PHP is not a _client-side_ language.

Comment: @IMB: Yes, that code is written in PHP.  But clients won't be POSTing to your API using PHP.  They're be POSTing to it using JavaScript, in all probability.

Comment: Yes that is written in PHP obviously, but the data is transmitted as JSON. Wait, why are we arguing about this? Regardless whether it's PHP, ASP, JS, etc, it is `json encoded`. The question is between clients sending as POST array vs POST JSON. Both can be accomplished no matter what language.

Comment: Look, now you're saying `clients won't be POSTing to your API using PHP. They're be POSTing to it using JavaScript` but yesterday you were saying `clients will be sending POST data to you.` You are confused :-)

Comment: As you can see both ways are possible. My question is simply what is the best way to go. Me being the server, should I accept POST data array or accept POST data in JSON string? There, I hope that is super clear.

Comment: @IMB: You are confusing what your code examples are _written in_ with what _format the data is being sent in_.  Both of your examples are _written in_ PHP.  I was saying that this doesn't make sense, because _clients_ sends requests to your server, and they won't be doing it using PHP.  They'll most likely be doing it using JavaScript.  If you still don't understand, I don't think further discussion will clarify.  Good luck to you.

Comment: Ok, I think I know why you are confused. You mention this `I've never heard of an API that understood serialized PHP array format` so you are thinking that I assume clients will send me in PHP serialized data? Of course not. I am not sure how you came up with that when my example doesn't even say I am sending serialize PHP data.

Comment: Both of my examples are sending POST array and POST JSON which can be read by PHP, ASP, JSP, Ruby, Python, or whatever server side language.

Comment: @drrcknlsn I actually came to this page because I had an exact same question. Answering questions is one thing, but starting it with a qualified 'this is dumb' is not the way to start it, especially since the context makes it fairly clear.

Comment: @Pier1Sys: His context didn't (and still doesn't) match his actual question, and I made note of that mismatch by saying that it wouldn't make sense to be posting to an API in the manner he used in his example.  When something doesn't make sense, I don't consider it insulting to say so.  I certainly didn't tell him that his question was "dumb" - that's your own misinterpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think this is a pretty good question. don't know why it got downvoted.

Also, contrary to what I saw written in some comments, the client can use any language he wants, not only javascript. And it's not the server job to know which language was used to "build" the request, just that the request is valid. This makes more sense if you think that the entity making the request can actually be another server (think about a proxy server used to send post requests across domains).

---

That being said, personally, I think it's better for the server side to consume a XML or JSON. The main reason is validation.

It's easier to validate a XML or JSON against a schema. 
Also the schema can be made public, and a well designed schema can describe webservice by itself. The client can even use the same schema to validate the request prior to sending it to the server.

Passing an url encoded form is also valid, of course. And can be validated server side as well. SO i think, down the road, it's just a matter of preference.

Also, check this discussion in SO, it regards the same topic:

[JSON vs Form POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604717/json-vs-form-post)

Answer (score 1):

You should think about the clients that will consume the API. A HTML5\AJAX client will probably want JSON data, while other clients (Silverlight or native mobile apps) might be better at consuming XML.

One great framework\platform for writing REST API's is looking to be Microsoft's Web API (based on ASP.NET MVC). The product succeeds the WCF framework and allows users to write REST API's in a MVC environment. One feature is that it chooses a serialization provider based on the HTTP Accept header.

So if a client Accepts application/json they work with the service in JSON and if the accept XML they work with the service in XML. You can also write your own object serializer and plug it into the framework.

More information: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/video-your-first-web-api

Comment: Note that is not about what the client consumes but what they send.

Comment: Still feels like if I'm best as consuming JSON, I'm going to want to request with a JSON formatted request and if I'm best at consuming XML... then I'm best at formatting XML requests. Web API handles serialization in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you would want to stick to receiving POST data but I think receiving json data does have its uses for example when it comes to batch requests.

The [Facebook API uses it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).

You don't need to do `file_get_contents('php//input')`. From the facebook documentation you could just do something like this:

curl -X POST "http://example.com/batch" -d 'batch={ "param" : 1, "param2" : "2"}'

Then in the PHP code, if you're using PHP, you can get it through the $_POST parameter and do a json_decode.

```
var_dump($_POST);

array(1) {
  ["batch"]=>
  string(30) "{ "param" : 1, "param2" : "2"}"
}

var_dump(json_decode($_POST['batch'], true));

array(2) {
  ["param"]=>
  int(1)
  ["param2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON makes more sense, since it is language-independent and can be useful when API scales.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but aren't all language able to send POST data as array?

Comment: He's saying that every platform will be able to read JSON, without fail. The PHP array format may be misinterpreted on certain platforms.

Comment: Why would I want to send an json encoded string to an api? I mean look at quite every restful api out there, you call the defined url with your parameters urlencoded in the body if it's a post, put or delete or in the url as parameters? Or did I miss something here?

Comment: @mAu Yeah, that is probably one of the main reason of my question.

Comment: Tablets. Smartphones. HTML5 Apps. They all benefit from JSON.

Comment: Well then I suggest you to url encode your php array in the `post` method and then send the request. Maybe take the [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) as an example.

Comment: @GundarsMēness but they consume the response. IMB was asking about the request. Not the response. Sure that the response being a json string fits most apis perfectly.

Comment: @GundarsMēness as reiterated by mAu this question is not about consuming data but sending.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently developing a `REST API` and I was asking myself the same question. After some research I found out that is no standard and is totally up to you.

You are developing the server side so you can decide how data should be sent to you. The client need to adapt to your design.

Personally I choose to receive all `POST` and `PUT` data as `JSON` directly in body.

Answer (score 0):

The point is to reuse the HTTP implementation that already exists.

HTTP is built to accept many different [content-types](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) and you only need to specify which you are using in the [headers](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

A REST API that accepts the various formats and works off the content-type header is refreshing. You can submit x-www-form-urlencoded values from an HTML webpage or make an AJAX request with raw JSON and there is no confusion as long as everyone is following protocol.

As a developer you must choose the support your app will provide because you can't support everything. Typically it boils down to the support or convenience of your own environment -- nobody wants to reinvent the wheel.

Many frameworks that are designed with building APIs in mind, handle the most popular content types at a lower level. They may also encode the response data according to the ["Accept" header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1).

Implement whatever you think will be used most first or find a framework that already speaks HTTP and takes care of all of that for you.